# Adding a BinarySecurityToken to cxf header

Tags: java, cxf

I've been pulling my hair out over this one and I just can't get it to work. I have a webservice I call that generates a security token which then needs to be passed to the subsequent service calls inside of the SOAP header. I got that part working just fine but the header part is tripping me up (I generated the client using cxf wsdl2java). This is the part that should be added:

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="XXXX" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" wsu:Id="SecurityToken">
  My token
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

I tried using a WSS4JOutInterceptor like this:

```
Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put("SecurityToken", MY-TOKEN);
endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps));
```

but that didn't work. And I tried directly adding it to the header like this (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807922/with-cxf-actually-groovyws-how-do-i-generate-a-soap-header-with-one-child-node)):

```
List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
SOAPElement authElement = sf.createElement(new QName(null, "wsse:BinarySecurityToken"));
authElement.setAttribute("ValueType", "XXXX");
authElement.setAttribute("EncodingType", "wsse:Base64Binary");
authElement.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "SecurityToken");
authElement.addTextNode(MY-TOKEN);
SoapHeader tokenHeader = new SoapHeader(
  new QName(null, "wsse:BinarySecurityToken"), authElement);
headers.add(tokenHeader);
((BindingProvider) service).getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
```

and it looks almost ok

```
<soap:Header><BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" ValueType="XXXX" wsu:Id="SecurityToken">MY-TOKEN</BinarySecurityToken></soap:Header>
```

The BinarySecurityToken part is missing the wsse: prefix though and the call fails.

Has anyone gotten something similar to work – or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: you got an answer to this problem?

Comment: @zengr see the answer posted below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@zengr Yes, I finally figured it out, it was missing the namespaces so what I did was this:

```
private static final String XMLNS_WSU = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";
private static final String XSD_WSSE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";

final List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
final SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
final SOAPElement securityElement = sf.createElement("Security", "wsse", XSD_WSSE);
final SOAPElement authElement = sf.createElement("BinarySecurityToken", "wsse", XSD_WSSE);
authElement.setAttribute("ValueType", "WASP");
authElement.setAttribute("EncodingType", "wsse:Base64Binary");
authElement.setAttribute("wsu:Id", "SecurityToken");
authElement.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), XMLNS_WSU);
authElement.addTextNode(StringUtils.replace(SessionToken.getEncodedSessionToken(), "\n", ""));
securityElement.addChildElement(authElement);
final SoapHeader securityHeader = new SoapHeader(
        new QName(null, "Security"), securityElement);
headers.add(securityHeader);
((BindingProvider) interactiveService).getRequestContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
```

And that did the trick

Comment: Dear @Jan what should be the content of SessionToken.getEncodedSessionToken() method? Does it return GUID?

Comment: @WinstonSmith really sorry but this is such a long time ago… I'll check in the office tomorrow if the code is still around. You might have more luck checking out .net related stuff in the meantime.

Comment: Can you help me in my question? I'm using axis2 instead of cxf, I don't have those methods to add headers (i'm using similar) but I can switch to cxf, I just need to sign the soap message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63482746/adding-binarysecuritytoken-to-a-wsdl2java-client-generated-axis2

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. I had similar case except I had to add token within an element of an element under header. This is trivial, but I paste solution here for more complete documentation.

```
    String token = "authentication token given from service";
    SOAPFactory sf = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPElement authElement = sf.createElement(new QName("urn:example.com", "Authentication"));
    SOAPElement tokenElement = sf.createElement(new QName(null, "AuthenticationToken"));
    tokenElement.addTextNode(token);
    authElement.addChildElement(tokenElement);
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    Header dummyHeader = new Header(new QName("urn:example.com"), authElement); 
    headers.add(dummyHeader);
```

which resulted in

```
<S:Header><Authentication xmlns="urn:example.com"><AuthenticationToken>authentication token given from service</AuthenticationToken></Authentication></S:Header>
```